# Why display:table gives extra spacing?

Tags: css

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjxzX/2/).

.li fits .box(pink), but when .box is display:table (yellow), li and .box has a gap between.  I checked, there is no margin or padding.

How to remove the gap?

```
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="box table">table</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="box">box</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but try playing around with `border-collapse:collapse` and `border-spacing:0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ the problem only appears in Chrome, not in Firefox

2/ The problem may lie with default display of list items: http://jsfiddle.net/MjxzX/11/ (I brought back left padding on list and margin+padding on LI). `display: table` will force content to occupy the whole line and it confers Block Formatting Context which has very special effects, that may be related (though I'm not sure. Edit: Mmh probably not as Firefox doesn't display it the same way...)

3/ You can apply *on list items* `display: block` or remove their bullets (edit: `list-style-type: none`), that will solve your problem on Chrome: resp. http://jsfiddle.net/MjxzX/13/ and http://jsfiddle.net/MjxzX/12/

Answer (score 0):

As the class table is using `display: table` you are having the margin at the top.

You can avoid that by using `display: block`

Another option is to use

```
-webkit-margin-before: -18px;
```

It will also remove the margin at the top.

The `display: table` will add margin in all webkit browsers. So i am adding the negative margin for only the webkit browsers.

Comment: You're using 2 definitions of "margin": margin in natural language as synonym of "there's a gap" and then CSS margin property with a magic value of `-18px` (I guess it's the line height but such a magic value with no explanation doesn't seem very robust and future-proof to me). And how is vertical centering related to the question?

Comment: I have updated the answer. The display: table will add margin in all webkit enabled browsers. So i am adding webkit specific syntax to add negative margin.

Comment: Let's apply `display: table` to list items: I don't see any margin that'd be applied by Chrome on them: http://jsfiddle.net/MjxzX/17/